# Prime generator in Fortran

Tags: fortran, primes

I'm just trying to get a little familiar with Fortran (because I can) so I wrote this small program that uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes to generate primes. Here is the program:

```
program prime
implicit none
integer num_primes, at, found, i
logical is_prime
integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: primes ! array that will hold the primes
print *, "How many primes would you like to find?"
read (*, *) num_primes
allocate (primes(num_primes))
primes(1) = 2
at = 2
found = 1
do
    is_prime = .true. ! assume prime
    do i = 1, found
        if (modulo(at, primes(i)) == 0) then ! if divisible by any other element
            is_prime = .false.               ! in the array, then not prime.
            at = at + 1
            continue
        end if
    end do
    found = found + 1
    primes(found) = at
    print *, at
    at = at + 1
    if (found == num_primes) then ! stop when all primes are found
        exit
    endif
end do
```

end program prime

Running this will show what the error is, for example, trying to find 10 primes will yield the following numbers: 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23. Obviously 16 is not prime. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working program by implementing Henrik suggestion (and then I did a few formatting changes):

```
program prime
implicit none

integer :: num_primes, at, found, i
logical :: is_prime
integer, allocatable, dimension(:) :: primes ! array that will hold the primes

print *, "How many primes would you like to find?"
read(*, *) num_primes
allocate(primes(num_primes))
primes(1) = 2
at = 2
found = 1
do
    is_prime = .true. ! assume prime
    do i = 1, found
        if (modulo(at, primes(i)) == 0) then ! if divisible by any other element
            is_prime = .false.               ! in the array, then not prime.
            exit
        end if
    end do
    if (is_prime) then
        found = found + 1
        primes(found) = at
        print *, at
    end if
    at = at + 1
    if (found == num_primes) then ! stop when all primes are found
        exit
    end if
end do
end program prime
```

When you run this, you'll get:

```
 How many primes would you like to find?
20
           3
           5
           7
          11
          13
          17
          19
          23
          29
          31
          37
          41
          43
          47
          53
          59
          61
          67
          71
```

and the `primes` array will contain all the prime numbers. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Performance could be improved by incrementing `at` by 2 instead of 1 as well as calculating sqrt(at) and quit checking primes larger than it. One other thing is that it doesn't print out the first prime, 2, even though it correctly prints out (in this example) the 20th prime.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which doesn't need `modulo`.
It's sort of trial division, but when you find a divisor, you increment `at` by 1 and start testing with the next prime where you should re-start. 
When you find 15 is divisable by 3, `at` is incremented to 16 and tested against 5, 7, an 11, which are of course not divisors of 16 and so 16 is printed.

I'm not a FORTRAN programmer, but I think you should replace the lines

```
at = at + 1
continue
```

by

```
exit
```

and execute the lines

```
found = found + 1
primes(found) = at
print *, at
```

only if is_prime is true.

Comment: What I intend for is the array called "primes" to contain all of the prime numbers. I put 2 in there initially, then it tests 3, 3 is not divisible by 2 so it is prime, then 4. 4 is divisible by 2 so not prime, continue... then 15, 15 is not divisible by 2 but is divisible by 3, so not prime. Then 16, it is divisible by 2 so not prime! This is a sort of Seive of Eratosthenes, but it's more, dynamic (I guess), all I'm doing is trial division by primes, which is what the Seive is essentially. I don't though understand your explanation.